# Jenkins - How to replay lastSuccessfulBuild inside pipeline job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a declarative jenkinsfile, with `currentBuild.currentResult` I check after every stage the build status, if all stages are good.

I deploy the new version in my final stage but if one stage fail I would like to launch the replay of the `lastSuccessfulBuild` inside the final stage of my jenkinsfile.
Is it even possible?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What's the purpose of re-running that stage?

Comment: I don't want to re-running my last stage, but re-running my last successful build
for always have a stable version deployed, I know jenkins have a "replay" button, but I would like to launch the replay directly in the jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Re-running the last successful build just for the purpose of re-deployment is the wrong approach. Think of the builds that they relate to a commit in your repo. And that build was already successful, so there is no need to run it again. Besides that, it could fail during the replay, e.g. when an external service like your binary repository is out of order.

Instead, change your deployment a way that the new version is deployed in parallel to the old version, then you only switch over if the deployment has been successful. It could work like this:

For example, you can use Ansible for that. Or, if you use Docker, you can use Kubernetes / OpenShift. If and only if the deployment was successful, your load balancer / proxy switches over to the new service. If the deployment failed, everything stays as it is.